# How can one solve $e^{x}=\left(2x\right)^{2+x}$?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

This logarithmic equation is boggling my mind. I've gotten to: $x=2\ln\left(2\right)+2\ln\left(x\right)+x\ln\left(2x\right)$ but I don't see any other rules or operations that I can use to proceed, like maybe **Lambert** or something, but I can't see that working yet. How can I finish solving it **algebraically**? (It could technically be treated as an **intersection of the system**: $y=e^{x}, y=\left(2x\right)^{2+x}$ and anyways one would have to equate them to each other)

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect a solution to exist?

Comment: I've seen that a solution exists graphically at approximately 0.636532904768113.

Comment: You said you wanted to solve it algebraically. Do you have any reason to expect a solution to exist?

Comment: I think Camishere 45 wants the solution, which exists, by any means and preferentially by "algebraic" manipulations of formulae, and that's not a big problem if the result isn't algebraic -- transcendental will be ok.

Comment: @LoutchoGlotuk what Arthur is saying is that there's no reason to expect a closed form solution to exist, so we (probably) can't do any better than the numerical approximation OP already gave. It's not just that we would need to use transcendental functions, but we can't get a closed form at all.

Comment: Then is there an algebraic method to approximate? Like Newton-Raphson for polynomial roots, is there something similar that can be applicable here?

Comment: "Like Newton-Raphson for polynomial roots" Newton-Raphson works for anything differentiable (continuously differentiable?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an highly transcendental equation and you will need some numerical method.

Consider that you are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=e^{x}-\left(2x\right)^{2+x}$$ If you plot it, it is not very nice.

Take logarithms and consider instead
$$g(x)=x -(2+x)\log(2x)$$ which looks better. By inspection $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $g(1)=1-3 \log (2)$.

To get an *approximation*, expand $g(x)$ as series around $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to obtain
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-4 \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+3
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{14}{3}
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{22}{3} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^6\right)$$ and use series reversion
$$x=\frac{1}{2}-t+\frac{3 t^2}{4}+\frac{t^3}{24}-\frac{83 t^4}{192}+O\left(t^5\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{1}{4} \left(g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Making $g(x)=0$ then gives
$$x_0=\frac{166863}{262144}\approx 0.636532$$

For an exact solution, use Newton method which would generate the following sequence of iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.500000 \\
 1 & 0.625000 \\
 2 & 0.636466 \\
 3 & 0.636533
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using methods of higher orders, we can generate better and better rational approximations which make the sequence
$$\left\{\frac 12,\frac{5}{8},\frac{37}{58},\frac{7}{11},\frac{1487}{2336},\frac{10891}{17110}
   ,\frac{1196527}{1879754},\frac{15336388}{24093637},\frac{224654839}{352935130},
   \frac{1234069748}{1938736801},\cdots\right\}$$

For the fun of it, I generated as an *estimate*
$$x=\frac{253576529534631568901058002580214066210601258174105279}{398371439457648761477
   649787337874565664330106193949998}$$